# como puedo llenar un input con id= ejemplo[], de tipo array desde javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

archivo.php

```
<input type='number' name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad[]' value='0'>

<input type='number' name='precio[]' id='precio[]' value='0'>

<input type='number' name='total[]' id='total[]' value='0'>
```

el cual me genera muchos registros a partir de un botón, y con el siguiente código obtengo los valores de los `array`

archivo.js

```
var cantidad = document.formulario_nueva_compra.elements['cantidad[]'];

var pu = document.formulario_nueva_compra.elements['precio[]'];
```

y de la siguiente manera calculo el precio total de cada registro

```
var total = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < cantidad.length; i++) {

  total[i]=cantidad[i].value*pu[i].value;

}
```

mi pregunta es: ahora como hago para enviar la variable `total[]` con todos los cálculos al `input` con `id='total[]'`. por favor si alguien pudiera ayudarme...

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que tienes un input (tipo text o hidden), similar a este:

```
<input type="text" id="total" name="total" />
```

Sugiero que muestres los resultados concatenados separados por una coma:

```
document.getElementById("total").value = total.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Para tu ejemplo estas utilizando el `id="total[]"` por lo tanto para asignarle el valor es necesario llamar el identificador `total[]` y asignarle el valor ejemplo

```
document.getElementById("total[]").value = total.toString();
```

Como sugerencia es mejor que llames los identificadores sin caracteres especiales, espero pueda ayudarte